# <trace> tag in web.config makes site run normal. Without it, it runs extremely slow

Tags: web-applications, web-config, iis-8

I have a very strange problem. I have a webapplication that runned very smoothly. Last week I moved the webapplication from a server with Windows 2012 en SQL Server 2016, to a new server with Windows 2019 and SQL Server 2019. The new server has more CPU's, more memory.

But when I open my site and try to save changes, it's unacceptably slow. It can take minutes to save. The problem is not the database, I've checked that. Running the same locally on my dev-PC, no problem.

Now I've added the following to my web.config to trace and try to figure out the problem. And that's the strange thing. With this it runs at normal speed.

How can this be? I don't want trace to be enabled for security reasons. But when I remove it, my webapp is slow again.

Anyone any answers?

Comment: Please enable failed request tracing for both <trace> enable and disable condition. Plesae compare the FRT log and post the process/module that spend a lot of time. This behavior looks strange so we need more information to fix this.

Comment: I've enabled Failed Request Tracing in IIS, but the log remains empty.

Comment: I think that might happened in runtime. Did you enable debugging in compilation section?